# why I cannot configure the network on my server when I try to install Debian 6?

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I am trying to install Debian Squeeze on a server(old one), when comes the part of network, it shows me the options

> Broadcom Corporation Netxtrem BCM5704 Gigabit Ethernet (as eth0 and
>   eth2)

and

> Inter corporation 82546EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (cooper)  (as
>   eth1 and et3),

so, if i choose eth0 or eth1 there is an error saying couldnt read the dhcp server (I have a router that assigns me IP , like a dhcp server) the weird part is that yesterday worked... so, I have no idea why now is not working, could be because yesterday internet was faster? still, should connect it now... when I configure the network manually I set 192.168.1.X (I figure the IP is free... and I set 77) , as gateway my router ip 192.168.1.1 and netmask 255.255.255.0 ...

It continues, formatting and all, but when it has to connect with the package manager does not work again! ... and I can not configure it, if I dont connect later I get no internet connection, I followed the steps to turn on the network after install without internet but didnt work... any help please? any idea what could be wrong with all this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit your /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
auto eth3
iface eth3 inet dhcp
```

doing this will make all 4 nic ports auto-up and DHCP when a network cable is plugged in.